# SSIS Project - Catalog Deployment - Environment Variable (for location) accessing file server mapped to a local Z drive - SQL Server Agent issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, environment-variables, sql-agent, foreach-loop-container

I have an SSIS package that reads a number of files using a For Each Loop Container. There are a number
of parameters in this package, and in the Integration Services Catalog in the SSMS, I have created an 
environment with many variables for this project/package.

There are a number of environment variables for this package. There is a particular environment variable for Source Location.

While in my DEV setting, I was able to pass the Source Location environment variable as :

```
C:\Data Repository\Files    (in a local machine).
```

Everything fine. Package runs perfectly, and For Each Loop Container works reads the files.

However, in the PROD setting, I have to use a file server, mapped to a Z drive.

For example:

```
This PC > Data Repository (\\tordfs) (Z:) > Data Repository > X
```

becomes

```
Z:\Data Repository\X
```

when I copy the path.

Inside the SSIS package, I am able to set the parameter value for Source Location as `Z:\Data Repository\X`
and the For Each Loop Container works fine from the SSDT/Visual Studio.

Now after the SSIS package/project is deployed to the SSMS Catalog, when I feed `Z:\Data Repository\X` as a value for the Source Location environment variable, and I Execute the package **manually** from the Catalog, **it works fine.**

However, when I use the **SQL Server Agent** for the above process, I get the **following error**:

> For Each Loop Container:Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty.
>   The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that
>   matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was
>   empty.

Is there anything I need to do in the For Each Loop Container or the SSIS Catalog to eliminate the above error during execution from the Catalog  using SQL Server Agent?

Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows mapped drives are user-specific.  So you would have to map the drive for the account running the package.  Instead use a UNC Path in both cases, and not a drive letter.

So something like:

```
\\tordfs\Data Repository\Files
```

The account running the package will still need permissions to the share, and permissions to the folder, but won't need a drive letter mount.

Comment: Thanks David and Hadi; I have a major production delivery next week; finally fixed !

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions:

1. Try giving read/write permissions to the SQL Database Engine Service account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$<Instance Name>` *(Where `<Instance Name>` should be replaced by the installed instance name)*:

   - [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Try to Map the Z:\ network drive within SQL Server:

   - [Make Network Path Visible For SQL Server Backup and Restore in SSMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3499/make-network-path-visible-for-sql-server-backup-and-restore-in-ssms/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. Appreciate it.

I think I have fixed the issue:

In the environment variable, you cannot have **Z:\Data Repository\X**

The variable must have the values such as this:

**\\tordfs\Data Repository\Data Repository\X**

While manual execution from SSMS Integration Services Catalog can accept    Z:\Data Repository\X     as a value of an environment variable,

the SQL Server Agent needs **\\tordfs**\Data Repository\Data Repository\X

If the SQL Server Agent when reading from the environment in Catalog reads **Z:**\Data Repository\X,

I get the For Each Loop Container posted above!

This said, I am using a proxy for the SQL Server Agent to resolve other access issues such as moving a file into a folder using the File System Task.

Comment: Well done! But since you decided to write your own answer, i think you should up-vote others answers instead of saying Thanks because they are both correct.

Comment: `In the environment variable, you cannot have Z:\Data Repository\X` **This is not true**. You have to add permission for the SQL Server service account as mentioned in Hadi's answer. Or you have to use UNC path as you mentioned